# form wizard com viacep

Tags: javascript, html5, json

Estou com um problema no preenchimento automático do formulário ao colocar o cep no form wizard, em um formulário separado dá certo.

Com form wizard:

[image: Com form wizard]

Sem form wizard:

[image: Sem form wizard]

JavaScript:

```
// chamada da api de CEP
function formulário_cep() {
    // Limpa valores do formulário de cep.
    $("#rua").val("");
    $("#bairro").val("");
    $("#cidade").val("");
    $("#uf").val("");
    $("#ibge").val("");
}

//Quando o campo cep perde o foco.
$("#cep").blur(function() {

    //Nova variável "cep" somente com dígitos.
    var cep = $(this).val().replace(/\D/g, '');

    //Verifica se campo cep possui valor informado.
    if (cep != "") {

        //Expressão regular para validar o CEP.
        var validacep = /^[0-9]{8}$/;

        //Valida o formato do CEP.
        if(validacep.test(cep)) {

            //Preenche os campos com "..." enquanto consulta webservice.
            $("#rua").val("...");
            $("#bairro").val("...");
            $("#cidade").val("...");
            $("#uf").val("...");
            $("#ibge").val("...");

            //Consulta o webservice viacep.com.br/
            $.getJSON("https://viacep.com.br/ws/"+ cep +"/json/?callback=?", function(dados) {

              if (!("erro" in dados)) {
                    //Atualiza os campos com os valores da consulta.
                    $("#rua").val(dados.logradouro);
                    $("#bairro").val(dados.bairro);
                    $("#cidade").val(dados.localidade);
                    $("#uf").val(dados.uf);
                    $("#ibge").val(dados.ibge);
                } //end if.
                else {
                    //CEP pesquisado não foi encontrado.
                    limpa_formulário_cep();
                    alert("CEP não encontrado.");
                  }
                });
        } //end if.
        else {
            //cep é inválido.
            limpa_formulário_cep();
            alert("Formato de CEP inválido.");
          }
    } //end if.
    else {
        //cep sem valor, limpa formulário.
        limpa_formulário_cep();
      }
    });
```

HTML

```
      <form method="get" action=".">
        <label>Cep:
          <input name="cep" type="text" id="cep" value="" size="10" maxlength="9" /></label><br />
          <label>Rua:
            <input name="rua" type="text" id="rua" size="60" /></label><br />
            <label>Bairro:
              <input name="bairro" type="text" id="bairro" size="40" /></label><br />
              <label>Cidade:
                <input name="cidade" type="text" id="cidade" size="40" /></label><br />
                <label>Estado:
                  <input name="uf" type="text" id="uf" size="2" /></label><br />
                  <label>IBGE:
                    <input name="ibge" type="text" id="ibge" size="8" /></label><br />
                  </form>
```